# Trouble using the sieve of eratosthenes

Tags: c++, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Given a number k, i have to find the smallest number which is not prime and does not divide with the first k prime numbers. I used the sieve of eratosthenes algorithm but i always get the result 1. I can`t understand why because **i** starts from 2. Any suggestions?

```
#define lim 100000
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

bool prim [lim];
int i,j,k,c,n;

fstream f("prim.in");
ofstream g("prim.out");

int main()
{
  f>>k;
  for(i=2;i<=lim;i++)
  {
    if(prim[i]==0)
    {
      c++;
      for(j=i*2;j<=lim;j+=i)
        prim[j]=1;
    }
    if(prim[i]==0)
      if(c==k+1) { g << i*i; return 0;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code?

Comment: the answer is still 1

Comment: The debugger does not correct your code. It allows you to follow program flow step by step. Check it and try to find where's the error.

Comment: `<=lim` Array indices in C++ don't work this way. The last index of `prim` is 99999. When you loop over an array of size `size`, you almost always want your condition to look like `i < size`.

Comment: In addition, you want to use the boolean constants `true` and `false`, and initialize your variables explicitly rather than rely on zero-initialization.

Comment: Replace `<=lim` with `<lim` and you will be able to see a different result. Indexes are from 0 to SIZE-1, so your code produces an overflow and badly sets the value of `i` when executing `prim[100000]=1`.

Comment: I initialized them in the main program and it works now. Thank you!